# Using RTL8188eu wifi AP with a Smart Wifi Plug

Tags: 16.04, wireless, realtek-wireless, ap-hotspot

I have a Wifi dongle with a RTL8188eu Chipset connected to my Ubuntu desktop.

I was finally able to create a Wifi Hotspot with it by using a bunch of tutorials

It shares the internet connection I get from LAN and I can connect to the hotspot with my Android phone and browse the internet

My goal is to connect a wifi plug to the hotspot, but so far the Smart plug app couldn't connect to the Hotspot. It just says a generic message saying "Couldn't connect". Smart plug works fine with a regular wifi connection

How do I even start to debug this ? Is there a way I can check come linux logs to see what's going on ?